# How many recombinations occur in an average human chromosome?

Tags: molecular-genetics

And is it a different number depending on which chromosome we choose (disregarding the change of this probability due to the differential size of the chromosomes)?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Unfortunately, this is really too broad... It will definitely depend which chromosome you chooose, and in any case, recombination can occur during mitosis or meiosis... You'll really need to narrow down your question.  Thanks!

Comment: I was asking about recombination during meiosis, the recombination that homologous chromosomes undergo to produce gametes. I had no idea recombination took place during mitosis, unless you mean something totally different to meiotic recombination that happens to have the same name. So the question would remain like this: how many sites of recombination are there in, say, chromosome 1? (Although I would also like to know how much that number varies along every chromosome).